# Arabic font breaks on iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, arabic, arabic-support

We are working in iOS app and we are using "Adobe Arabic" and "Tahoma" font.

Both fonts in some area break. For example

Tahoma breaks by adding space between in a single word as shown in image below[image]

Not sure why this is happening for some works. We have similar issue for Adobe Arabic for some Arabic text

Mostly font breaks when using verses from quran "بِسْمِ اللَّـهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ" otherwise it is fine... That is when ever we add tajweed font break by adding space.

What could be the possible reason for this

Comment: Have you tried to include other fonts with your app?

Comment: It should not break at-least with Tahoma, as we have been using this for on website etc.. May be issue could be with the font type. eot or ttf. I will update once we find a solution

Answer (score 4):

As I see, its failing to render diacritics. Diacritics should be merged to their previous letters in Arabic. In your example, it breaks with the Shada diacritic `ّ`  :

[image]

It happens mostly in Quranic verses because they are fully vocalized compared to normal texts.

A solution is to normalize your texts and strip diacritics. The list of diacritcs is:

```
// Diacritics
'0x64b' // FatHatan
'0x64c' // Dammatan
'0x64d' // Kasratan
'0x64e' // FatHa
'0x64f' // Damma
'0x650' // Kasra
'0x652' // Sukun
'0x651' // Shadda
```

The normalization is recommended for normal text but not Quran verses since its considered as a holy text and recommended to be written as fully vocalized Uthmani script. You may use pre-rendered images.

A deep solution  is to use a rendering engine like [harfbuzz](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/HarfBuzz/). It renders Arabic perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in css:

```
.element {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

It works with me.

Comment: how can you use css with IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try these in your css

`font-family: "Traditional Arabic", "Montserrat","sans-serif","Times New Roman";`